# Reference: hitting time of Gaussian process

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, gaussian, large-deviations

Let $X_t$ be an OU process and $Y_t$ be the Gaussian process defined by
$$
Y_t = y+\int_0^t X_s ds + W_t,
$$
for some Brownian motion independent of $X_t$.  Let $y,a>0$; is there a large deviation result, describing the hitting time of $Y_t$ to $a$?

I've seen similar results in other papers, for example [here](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdfview_1/euclid.aop/1196268681) but I can't seem to find this type of result...

More precisely, if $a\geq 0$ and $\tau_a$ is the hitting time defined by
$$
\tau_a\triangleq inf \left\{
t>0: \, |Y_t|\leq a
\right\},
$$
then is there a result quantifying $f$ where $f$ satisfies a large-deviation principle of the form
$$
\ln \mathbb{P}\left(
\tau_a >x
\right) \leq f(x)
,
$$
and $f(x)$ is a $C^1$-function of $x$.

Comment: Can you state more precisely the inequality you want to prove?

Comment: Sure, I've made it more precise.

Comment: Please proofread your definition of $\tau_a$

Comment: Are you sure you want $|Y_t| \le a$ rather than $|Y_t| \ge a$? If so then $W_0$ must be nonzero.

Comment: That's fine, I adjusted for that to make things clear

Comment: Sorry, the question still is indecipherable. Is $W_0=0$ or not? Note my previous question on the direction of the inequality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since they are independent, lets start with treating $W_{t}$ as a deterministic Holder-continuous function (and so lets interpret it as the t-dependent mean of the first term).

Indeed, in ["Hitting times for Gaussian processes"](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0606086.pdf) they develop an LT estimate for hitting time. But you have a lot more eg. Markov structure. In ["On the first-passage time of an integrated Gauss-Markov process"](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1506.01155.pdf) they study integrated processes and rewrite them as a BM

[image]

From here they can extract some formulas.

Generally though there are quite a few hits even under "integrated Ornstein Uhlenbeck" and hitting times/exists eg. ["The one-sided barrier problem for an integrated ornstein-uhlenbeck process.](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/15326349108807200)".